# Canon TS9020 driver Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: printing

I am using 16.04 LTS.  I need a driver for Canon TS9020.  This printer is not in the database.  I did fint it in Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/inkjet-multifunction/ts-series-inkjet/ts9020-white?tab=drivers#Z7_MQH8HIC0L88RB0AMD0F1Q42K25

Comment: I have answered the post on the Ubuntu Forum; Hardware section; where you ask this issue